# How to dynamically create columns in SQL based on a list of ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am developing a stored procedure in SQL that receives a list of Ids (INT) from the backend. I need to dynamically create columns based on these and give the columns for each ID a name. Below is an example of how to do this with a fixed number of known Ids

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SE.SE_optionCode AS OptionCode,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(DO.DO_Description)) AS Description,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(CASE WHEN DG.DG_Description IS NULL THEN '' ELSE DG.DG_Description END)) AS GenericDescription,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(CASE WHEN DG.DG_GenericCode IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE DG.DG_GenericCode END))  as GenericCode,
    DCS.DC_CatCode AS Category,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(DCS.DC_Description)) AS Category,
    DCG.DC_CatCode AS GenericCategory,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(DCG.DC_Description)) AS GenericCategory,
    (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM NVDStandardEquipment WHERE SE_id = 93762 AND SE_optionCode = SE.SE_optionCode AND SE.SE_effectiveTo IS NULL) as Vehicle1,
    (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM NVDStandardEquipment WHERE SE_id = 93786 AND SE_optionCode = SE.SE_optionCode AND SE.SE_effectiveTo IS NULL) as Vehicle2,
    (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM NVDStandardEquipment WHERE SE_id = 93787 AND SE_optionCode = SE.SE_optionCode AND SE.SE_effectiveTo IS NULL) as Vehicle3,
    (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM NVDStandardEquipment WHERE SE_id = 93801 AND SE_optionCode = SE.SE_optionCode AND SE.SE_effectiveTo IS NULL) as Vehicle4        
FROM NVDStandardEquipment SE (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN NVDDictionaryOption DO (NOLOCK) ON DO.DO_OptionCode = SE.SE_optionCode
INNER JOIN NVDDictionaryOptionGenericCatLink DOGCL (NOLOCK) ON DOGCL.OGCL_OptionCatCode = DO.DO_CatCode
LEFT JOIN NVDDictionaryOptionGenericLink DOGL ON DOGL.ogl_optioncode = SE.SE_optionCode
LEFT JOIN NVDDictionaryGeneric DG ON DG.DG_GenericCode = DOGL.OGL_genericCode
INNER JOIN NVDDictionaryCategory DCS (NOLOCK) ON DCS.DC_CatCode = DO.DO_CatCode
INNER JOIN NVDDictionaryCategory DCG (NOLOCK) ON DCG.DC_CatCode = DOGCL.OGCL_GenericCatCode
WHERE SE.SE_id in (93762,93786,93787,93801)
```

This will return a result set as in the attached image.

[image: Results]

In my stored procedure I am declaring a temporary table where I store all the Ids received from the backend, somehow I would have to loop through these (Not sure if thats the best approach), I don't know whether is possible to generate the same output based on a ID list to generate the columns as per the example, has anyone done something similar or have some ideas about how I could achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `NOLOCK` is not a magic "go-faster" button, it's a magic "give incorrect results" button. How many possible extra columns would you need, and is it OK to have them statically named `Vehicle1`,`Vehicle2`... or do they *need* to be named according to the actual data?

Comment: They can be named Vehicle1 Vehicle2 and so on, no probs with that, even Derivative1 or Derivative2, doesn't really matter. Now, the amount of IDs can vary per request, might be 11, could be 3, could be 6, even 1 sometimes... thats the problem I'm facing

Comment: If You *"really* need" the `NOLOCK`s (I doubt it)  then either it should only be used against maybe 1 (or at worst 2) of the tables or you should be defining the entire batch's isolation level; no spamming `NOLOCK` against every table reference. It's actually *very* odd that you use `NOLOCK` against `NVDStandardEquipment` in the main `FROM`, but don't in any of the sub queries; which could give some very inconsistent results.

Comment: Yes but is there an absolute maximum, so we could just have a static query and the unneeded columns would all be `null`? Otherwise it needs to be dynamic SQL, which is very complex to write and maintain, and usually unnecessary

Comment: Why don't you store you data relationally i.e. in the rows of a child table rather that a dynamic number of columns?

Comment: So far I've just seen a max of 11 possible Ids in a given scenario I would say no more than 15-20, but I'm just guessing here, and I would need to bring back results for all of them ...

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you need to update/maintain the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test1](
    [MemberID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [InpatientDays] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ERVisits] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [OfficeVisits] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Narcotics] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DaysSinceLastERVisit] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Pain] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TotalVisits] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

You have a file with a list of the following IDs.

```
AcuteDrugGapSmall
ClaimLines
MedicalClaims
PoorCare
ProviderCount
StartedOnCombination
```

Create a table to save the IDs.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test2](
    [ID] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

After you insert the IDs run the following to generate the TSQL script to add the new columns. I'm assuming they're all VARCHAR(50) in this example. You can tweak to code given more information regarding data_type and character_maximum_length. You can take a similar approach to drop columns if needed. If you had a flag in table Test2 indicating whether to add or drop the column.

```
 DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG('ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Test1] ADD ' + ID  + ' VARCHAR(50)', '   ')
FROM [dbo].[Test3]

EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

The above script generates and executes the following. Please mark as solution if this works for you.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Test1] ADD AcuteDrugGapSmallVARCHAR(50)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Test1] ADD ClaimLinesVARCHAR(50)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Test1] ADD MedicalClaimsVARCHAR(50)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Test1] ADD PoorCareVARCHAR(50)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Test1] ADD ProviderCountVARCHAR(50)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Test1] ADD StartedOnCombinationVARCHAR(50)
```